# Camel sftp fails if there are a lot of files ( more as 10,000 ) in the remote directory queried

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

Did anyone encounter this behavior also and knows a solution? so_timeout seems the parameter to enlarge but I had no success with this.

In the log files I found caused by pipe closed.

A manual sftp and 'ls *' command took more as 20 minutes to get a listing back. So I guess it is a Camel timeout. Can this set per route?

```
2020-02-07T15:54:29,624 WARN  [com.bank.fuse.filetransfer.config.bankFileTransferManagerLoggingNotifier] (Camel (rabobank-file-transfer-manager-core) thread #4494 - sftp://server.eu/outgoing/attachments) ExchangeFailedEvent | RouteName: SAPSF-ONE-TIME-MIGRATION-18 | OriginatingUri: sftp://server.eu/outgoing/attachments?antInclude=*.pgp&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true&delay=20000&inProgressRepository=%23inProgressRepo-SAPSF-ONE-TIME-MIGRATION&knownHostsFile=%2Fhome%2Fjboss%2F.ssh%2Fknown_hosts&move=sent&onCompletionExceptionHandler=%23errorStatusOnCompletionExceptionHandler&password=xxxxxx&privateKeyFile=%2Fhome%2Fjboss%2F.ssh%2Fid_rsa&readLock=none&soTimeout=1800000&streamDownload=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&username=account | completedWithoutException: false | toEndpoint:  | owner: [SAP] | sm9CI: [CI5328990] | priority: [Low] | BreadcrumbId: ID-system-linux-bank-com-42289-1580217016920-0-5929700 | exception: Cannot change directory to: ..
```

Maybe soTimeout=1800000 was too short. A manual sftp and ls * command took about 20 minutes.

Since this was a one time action. I resolved it with a manual sftp.

Comment: Can you show your route (especially how you set the timeout) + the full stack trace ?

Comment: I have added the warning message I got in the logging. Unfortunately that is the only info I got. I configure routes but do not code them. Due to the long test times I can not just rerun the route.

Comment: At the end of the [WARN] message, I see - exception: Cannot change directory to: .. - Perhaps it is not a timeout, but a wrong directory configuration. Please double check your config.

Comment: exception: Cannot change directory to: .. is caused because the connection is terminated. I admit the logging is unclear.